# Circle Progress Bar JQuery plugin loop issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Issue:**
I am using the Circle Progress JQuery plugin (version: 0.6.0) for a project and have made some modifications to it, however, each circle seems to repeat itself (or loop) for an extended period of time rather than only performing the animation once.

Due to the modifications made, such as adding a link to where if it is clicked, the animation begins, doesn't seem to be where the issue lies.  It's when you start to scroll down, and when you do - every circle starts animating based on the percentage set but keeps repeating itself several times before it stops.  It should only start the animation for each circle once when the user scrolls down but I can't seem to figure out the root of why this is occurring.

**Here is what I have:**

```
$('.about_nav a:nth-of-type(2)').click(function () {
function animateElements() {
    $('.progressbar').each(function () {
        var elementPos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        var percent = $(this).find('.circle').attr('data-percent');
        var percentage = parseInt(percent, 10) / parseInt(100, 10);
        var animate = $(this).data('animate');
        if (elementPos < topOfWindow + $(window).height() - 30 && !animate) {
            $(this).data('animate', false); // Change this 'false -or- true' - Currently set to false so that each time a user clicks on 'Skill-set' link, animation occurs
            $(this).find('.circle').circleProgress({
                startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
                value: percent / 100,
                thickness: 2, // Change this for thickness
                fill: {
                    color: '#16A085'
                }
            }).on('circle-animation-progress', function (event, progress, stepValue) {
                $(this).find('.percent').text((stepValue*100).toFixed(0) + "%"); // NOTE: Change '.toFixed(0)' to '.toFixed(1)' to get 1 decimal place to the right...
            }).stop();
        }
    });
}

animateElements();
$('.about_body_wrapper').scroll(animateElements);
});
```

Here is a rough demo of what I mean: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/de41cppa/) - Click "Skill-set" tab and scroll down.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I think I've achieved what you wanted on [This updated(again) JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/de41cppa/5/)

basically, I set the `data-animate` property to true right before the animation begins, which stops any subsequent animate calls from animating it again (the looping issue you were seeing).

Then, I took the `animateElements` function definition out of the click handling event.  I did this so I could call it on a more global scope.  I now call `animateElements` in the click handler that changes the tabs.  Had to do that because it being fired on page load was making all the elements offsetTop = 0 because they started out hidden.

Lastly, I added an init property to the animate elements function which resets all the `data-animate` to false when `true`.  Its only true when called from a tab click, not by the scroll event.

heres the relevant code update:

...new init param (also have to make room for the scroll event passed in)

```
function animateElements(e, init) {
    if(init){
        $('.progressbar').data('animate', false);
    }
```

...animateElements is now initially called by the tab click handler

```
    $(currentlist).fadeOut(250, function () {
        $(newlist).fadeIn(200, function(){
            animateElements({}, true);
        });
    });
```

lastly, note theres a bunch of stuff in there now you can cut out now that I forgot to in the jsfiddle from when I was proving the concept.

cheers!

Comment: This is really close...However, all circles start over on scroll, it needs to be where each circle animation occurs right after the other on scroll and only occur once...Does that make sense?

Comment: So you need each cycle to start after the animation of the previous one complete?

Comment: Somewhat yes.  Once the visitor clicks on the link - the animation occurs for all but what is seen on the page.  Then once the user scrolls down, each circle animates one after the other depending on the frequency of user scrolling and should only occur once. - Then if a user decides to scroll back up, nothing happens since all circles animation has been completed - same would apply if the user decides to scroll back down...However, if the user clicks on the link again, the entire process (or animation of circles) start all over again.  Does that help explain what I'm going after?

Comment: I think the underlying issue resolves around here: `if (elementPos < topOfWindow + $(window).height() - 30 && !animate)` - it doesn't seem to recognize it for some reason...

Comment: Rooster, I appreciate all your help this far, truly I do!  It's definitely getting there...Is there a way to "reset" all animation if (for example) a user clicks on the history tab, and then back on the skill-set tab?  As it sits right now, this doesn't occur...I noticed you took out `animateElements();` at the bottom, I need this in there too...Instead of `$(window).scroll(animateElements);`, I'm using `$('.about_body_wrapper').scroll(animateElements);` but the fiddle didn't allow me to do that for some reason...and with your latest update, leaving out `animateElements();` isn't ideal...

Comment: @Michael sorry had to give my laptop to the girlfriend for now.  But thinking about it, all you'do have to do for what you described should be to have it reset all the `data-animate` properties of the circles to false whenever a new tab is clicked.  Try that out :D

Comment: @Michael alright, updated the answer one more time.  I think thats what you are looking for

Comment: @Rooster, Thank you for being persistent on this, I really appreciate all your help!  This iteration seems to be almost perfect!  I never would have thought to add the `animateElements({}, true);` to my `currentlist` and `newlist` declarations above...I was trying to keep them separate, but they do intermingle with one another now that I look at it from a fresh days perspective. Out of curiosity though, the `$('.about_nav a:nth-of-type(2)').click(function () {} );` can be commented out yes?  It isn't serving any real purpose anymore. Also, using the init attribute may not be feasible...What I

Comment: What I mean is that once the init takes place, there seems to be a small delay before the animation starts...This has to be because we took the click handler out of the equation and are relying on the javascript to load once the event is triggered.  Is there a way to eliminate that small delay and perhaps load the event in the background before the event is triggered?  That way, when the event is triggered, it instantly animates rather than having that small delay?  I think the root of this is because of the `init` but I could be wrong...Any thoughts?

Comment: And I apologize for sounding picky here...I'm just not to familiar with using the init variable...

I've also went ahead and marked your answer as correct, since you did help fix the issue of it looping...

Comment: I actually think the delay is caused because of the `animateElements({}, true);` being specified on line 45...Basically, if any link is clicked, the event (or animation) is triggered...And because of such, if you click on the history link, then back to the skill-set link quickly, you see that delay in animation.  How can we change this up a bit where the animation only occurs if the skill-set link is clicked.?

Comment: the delay is because of the 250 and 200 ms values you have that fade in and fade out, so the animateElements doesnt start until those finish fading.  Unfortunately, you cant get get offset top of any of those circles while theyre containing element is hidden.  You could try to adjust the fade times, or you could at least reset the animations when fading out.  That seems like it would probably be another question though if you run into trouble with that :D

Comment: @Rooster, could you check this out please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878486/circle-progress-bar-jquery-plugin-event-trigger-issue